# How to nest multiple MAX (...) statements in one CASE WHEN Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and currently I have something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('9') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has9,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('8') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has8
FROM xxxx
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
CASE WHEN 
    (MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('9') = 1 THEN 'has9' ELSE
    MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('8') = 1 THEN 'has8' ELSE 'FIX'
END as test_version
```

So far without success. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you use your MAX function to turn a single article_code column into two different columns (has9 and has8). In your second example, you are no longer splitting up your article_code column into multiple columns, therefore, as far as I can tell, you no longer need your MAX function.

Have you tried something along the following lines?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('9') THEN 'has9'
            ELSE SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('8') THEN 'has8'
            ELSE 'FIX'
       END as test_version
FROM xxxx
```

**EDIT:** Ah, in that case you will still need the MAX function to reduce it to a single line.

You should be able to use your original query as a subquery that gets a single line and then use a CASE WHEN to convert it to a single string:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN has9 = 1 THEN 'has9'
            WHEN has8 = 1 THEN 'has8'
            ELSE 'FIX'
       END as test_version
FROM (  SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('9') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has9,
               MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('8') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has8
        FROM xxxx )
```

Or, you could use my earlier query as subquery and use the MAX function to reduce it to a single line:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(result_rank) = 3 THEN 'has9'
            WHEN MAX(result_rank) = 2 THEN 'has8'
            ELSE 'FIX'
       END as test_version
FROM ( SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('9') THEN 3
                   ELSE SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('8') THEN 2
                   ELSE 1
              END as result_rank
       FROM xxxx )
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not totally getting this. When I do this without MAX the query returns multiple rows (the entiry query wants to check if a user has a certain product) but want I want is a single row. What happens if i nest this CASE WHEN statement in a MAX (...) expression?

Comment: Thanks Sam, that was exactly what I was looking for. It returns the desired result(s). However, why is the output different to when I write: `MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('9') THEN 'has9' ELSE CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) IN ('8') THEN 'has8' ELSE 'FIX' END END) AS test_version`... I don't understand this right now.

Comment: @user3387124 The `MAX(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` construction returns 1 if `<condition>` is valid for any row in the table and 0 otherwise. You first need to let your MAX function 'calculate' these values before you start doing comparisons with them. Doing this in a subquery is the easiests to read/understand I think. Btw: valex' answer is worth trying out at as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
SELECT 
      CASE 
           WHEN EXISTS(SELECT article_code 
                         FROM XXXX 
                        WHERE SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) = '9')
           THEN 'has9'
           WHEN EXISTS(SELECT article_code 
                         FROM XXXX 
                        WHERE SUBSTRING(article_code,5,1) = '8')
           THEN 'has8'
           ELSE 'FIX'
END CASE  as test_version;
```